# how to remove cell value in the cell offset if a new value with the same data repeated after that?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to make a loop in range to zero the offset cell if the cell data is repeated next as below:

```
    Column A          Column B
    T10               5
    T20               10 
    T10               15
```

You see I have T10 Repeated maybe after one or many rows, What I want is to use only the last value for T10 (Which is 15 in this example) and make 5 = 0

I use this code in vb.net

```
Private Sub AdjustTotalStoreWeightPerDiamater()
    wb = Workbook Path ...
    ws = Worksheet Name ...
    lr = last row
    Rng = Column Range
    Cel = Column Range
    i = integer

    With ws
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
        Rng = ws.Range("A2", "A" & lr)
    End With

    For i = 2 To lr
        For Each Cel In Rng.Cells
            If Cel.Value = Cel.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
                Cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
            End If
       Next
    Next
End Sub
```

But the code does not sense that T10 = T10 to make the change.

Appreciate your support.

Comment: Can you please clarify wether this code is VBA or VB.NET (it cannot be both, please adjust your tags accordingly).

Comment: @ PEH , This is VB.net

Answer (score 0):

I used OleDb to get the data from Excel as a `DataTable`. Note that I used `Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""` at the end of the connection string so we would get the column headers.

```
Private Function GetExcelData() As System.Data.DataTable
    Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
    Dim ConStr = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Code\TestCode3\TestCode3\bin\Debug\TestCode1.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
    Dim SheetName = "Sheet1$"
    Using cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand($"Select * From [{SheetName}];", cn)
            cn.Open()
            Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dt.Load(dr)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

To save the data back to the same excel sheet I used office automation.

```
Private Sub SaveDataTableToExcel(dt As System.Data.DataTable, RowToStartAt As Integer)
    Dim FileToOpen = "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Code\TestCode3\TestCode3\bin\Debug\TestCode1.xlsx"
    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb = DirectCast(xl.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen), Workbook)
    Dim ws = DirectCast(wb.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    'Add Headers
    For ColumnIndex = 1 To dt.Columns.Count
        ws.Cells(RowToStartAt, ColumnIndex) = dt.Columns(ColumnIndex - 1).Caption
    Next
    'Write data to Excel
    For dtRow = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        RowToStartAt += 1
        Dim xlColumnIndex = 1
        For Each dtcolumn As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            ws.Cells(RowToStartAt, xlColumnIndex) = dt(dtRow)(dtcolumn)
            xlColumnIndex += 1
        Next
    Next
    wb.Save()
    wb.Close()
    xl.Quit()
End Sub
```

The magic happens in happens in the Linq query where we group by Column A and select the Max from Column B. Then it is a simple loop through the returned enumerable to fill a new DataTable that is passed to Excel for saving.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim dt = GetExcelData()
    Dim e = From row In dt.AsEnumerable
            Group By TValue = row.Field(Of String)("Column A")
                    Into Ts = Group, Max(row.Field(Of Double)("Column B"))
            Select TValue, Max
    Dim Newdt = dt.Clone 'Copies structure but not data
    For Each row In e
        Newdt.Rows.Add({row.TValue, row.Max})
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Newdt 'Just checking if we got the expected data
    Dim WhereToAdd = dt.Rows.Count + 3 'Two rows down from original data
    SaveDataTableToExcel(Newdt, WhereToAdd)
    MessageBox.Show("Done")
End Sub
```